# Marker not updating coordinates in Google Maps for AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, angular-google-maps

I am using [Google Maps for AngularJS](http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/) and have the following Jade code:

```
#map_canvas
  google-map(center='map.center', zoom='map.zoom', draggable='true', options='options', events='map.events')
     marker(coords='marker.coords', options='marker.options', idkey='marker.id')
```

In my angular controller I have:

```
$scope.map = {center: {latitude: 42.2405, longitude: -8.7207 }, zoom: 12, events: {
        click: function (map, eventName, args) {
            $scope.marker.coords.latitude = args[0].latLng.lat();
            $scope.marker.coords.longitude = args[0].latLng.lng();
            console.log($scope.marker);
        }
    }
    }

$scope.marker = {
        id: 0,
        coords: {
            latitude: 42.2405, longitude: -8.7207
        },
        options: { draggable: true }
    }
```

What I am trying is to update the marker location with every click.
At `console.log($scope.marker);` I can see that my marker does print the updated coordinates value but the red pin does not move on the map.

I can't figure what I am doing wrong.

EDIT:

The marker does move to the new location after I resize the map, so I figured it is a matter of the map no refreshing when marker location changes. Should this be reported as a bug? Anything I can do to solve it?

Answer (score 3):

Finally! After reading a bit on $apply() [here](http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html) and [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply) and finding solutions like [this one](https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-google-maps/issues/399) where it mentions to:

> wrap your callback body into `$scope.$apply(function () { ... });`. Remember
>   that your event is coming from "non-Angular" world.

I found [this other post](https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-google-maps/issues/147) where it just adds `$scope.$apply();` to the end of the click function.

This last solution was the only one working for me. 
I've posted all the process cause I consider it interesting to learn about $apply().